# make svg snap image line up on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, snap.svg

Here is the code.
The svg is 1279 x 859.

How do I get the graphic to align its top-left corner to the 
Right now it lines up on the top-left corner of the browser's tab/window.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
        svg { position:fixed; top:0; left:0; height:100%; width:100%;
    }
    </style>

    <script src="/script/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



    <script src="/script/snap.svg.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/script/snap.svg.zpd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <div id="jqxPanel" style="padding: 20px; border:1px solid black; width: 1920px; height: 1080px">
        <div id="image" style="padding: 2px; border: 1px solid black"; width: 1290px; height: 870px">
            <svg id="SnapCanvas" ></svg>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var BaseSVG = Snap('#SnapCanvas');
        $(document).ready(function () {

            SVGElement.prototype.getTransformToElement = SVGElement.prototype.getTransformToElement || function (elem) {
                return elem.getScreenCTM().inverse().multiply(this.getScreenCTM());
            }

            Snap.load("Canvas.svg", function (f) {
                BaseSVG.append(f);
            });

        });
    </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the top-left corner is aligned to the right won't it be off screen/canvas? Would be easier to assist if you could provide this in a jsfiddle, you can use a cdn to reference in jQuery and Snapsvg. Otherwiseould suggest getting the canvas screen width and setting the graphic's (left) position accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A) You're missing some words from your questions. I'm assuming you mean to say, "How do I get the graphic to align its top-left corner to the top left corner of its container"

If so,

B)Your image has:

```
position: fixed;
```

Fixed positioning means that the element will measure its top, bottom, left, right values from the edge of the viewport (i.e. the window). What you want is:

```
position: absolute;
```

Positioning something absolutely means that its top, bottom, left, and right values will be measured from the edges of **its last positioned ancestor**. That part is important. None of it's ancestor elements are `positioned` by default. All elements have `position: static` by default. **`static` is the only value for the position property that is not considered `positioned`**. So, you need to change the position property of the svg's parent. I would change it to `relative` because it's least likely to screw with your styles.

At the end of the day your styles should look like this:

```
 svg { 
   position:absolute; 
   top:0; 
   left:0; 
   height:100%; 
   width:100%;
 }

 #image {
   position: relative;
 }
```

Edited for typos.

Comment: If took BOTH #image { position: relative } AND svg { position: absolute } to get the image to behave as expected.  As you suggested.  Thanks.